# Installing PERC driver during CentOS install

Tags: centos, redhat, installation, dell-poweredge, drivers

I'm trying to install CentOS on a PowerEdge R720, and I'm running into some issues with installing drivers during setup. I've created a virtual disk consisting of a single SSD, but during install CentOS doesn't 'see' the virtual disk. I'm fairly sure that I need [this driver](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=8JCD4&fileId=3529605296&osCode=RHE70&productCode=poweredge-r720&languageCode=en&categoryId=SF) to make CentOS recognize the disk, but I can't figure out how to install the driver during installation.

I know that during the install I have to get into the `boot:` prompt and type `linux dd`, and that comes up with a list of devices to select from to install drivers. The problem is that the drivers are in `.rpm` form, and searching for how to convert rpms to .dd files has been fruitless.

Here's some more information that may be useful:
 - The virtual disk seems to be online: [image]
 - The CentOS version is CentOS 7 - Everything - 1511

Comment: Do you mean R720? And what version of CentOS?

Comment: Sorry, yes I mean R720. CentOS 7

Comment: Huh this answer is probably gonna suck ... but have you tried just booting it w/o adding a driver? We've got a bunch of these with Cent7 and I haven't needed to add in the PERC driver

Comment: Same here.  CentOS 5, 6 and 7 using R720's, R730's, no need for driver disks.  No vendor packages at all.  We have sata, sas and ssd.  Are you trying to use JBOD on a H7xx or H8xx controller?

Comment: Interesting, I have tried booting it without a driver, and it definitely doesn't show up. I'm a noob at server administration though so I could have messed up something obvious during the raid setup. Where should I look in the BIOS to ensure I've set up RAID correctly?

Comment: Get on the iDrac, reboot the server, go into the raid config (it will prompt you for what keys to press) and verify your raid device was initialized and ready.

Comment: Easier way log into your drac, expand the storage node on the left, and the click on Virtual Disks (https://i.imgur.com/kDiMuYK.png)

Comment: Got it, added some more information to the post